# Switch-case statement not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a small program that basically works on a SWITCH statement. It reads each case within the switch statement and calls and executes the appropriate functions. But, I am facing a problem that, all the functions are getting executed when the first case of the switch statement is getting called. It should not be the case because only that function which is called by a particular switch-case statement should be executed. Can some one suggest me what is wrong with my code? Posting my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Security;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy;
namespace Excel1
{
    class WebServiceFunctions
    {
        private string siteID = "INDIA";
        static TemplateClient templateClient;
        static TaskClient taskClient;
        public WebServiceFunctions()
        {
            templateClient = new Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TemplateClient();
            templateClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "admin";
            templateClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "admin";
            templateClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

            taskClient = new Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskClient();
            taskClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "admin";
            taskClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "admin";
            taskClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
        }
        public void GetAllTemplateNames(String strSite, String strRetVal)
        {
            //GetAllTemplateNames
            Console.WriteLine("Invoking GetAllTemplate method");
            Console.WriteLine("List of all templates with details");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            List<Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TemplateData> tData = templateClient.GetAllTemplate(strSite).ToList();
            foreach (Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TemplateData data in tData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TemplateName:" + data.name);
                Console.WriteLine("TemplateDescription:" + data.description);
                Console.WriteLine("SiteName:" + data.site_name);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        }
        public List<TemplateData> ReturnAllTemplateNames()
        {
            // Console.WriteLine("Invoking GetAllTemplate method");
            // Console.WriteLine("List of all templates with details");
            // Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            List<Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TemplateData> tData = templateClient.GetAllTemplate(siteID).ToList();
            foreach (Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TemplateData data in tData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TemplateName:" + data.name);
                Console.WriteLine("TemplateDescription:" + data.description);
                Console.WriteLine("SiteName:" + data.site_name);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            return tData;
        }
        public void GetTaskInstanceFromTemplate(Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TemplateData data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoking GetTaskInstanceFromTemplate method");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskInstance tInstance = taskClient.GetTaskInstanceFromTemplate(siteID, data);
            if (tInstance != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TaskName: " + tInstance.name);
                Console.WriteLine("TaskDescription :" + tInstance.description);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        }
        public TaskInstance ReturnTaskInstanceFromTemplate(Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TemplateData data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoking GetTaskInstanceFromTemplate method");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskInstance tInstance = taskClient.GetTaskInstanceFromTemplate(siteID, data);
            if (tInstance != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TaskName: " + tInstance.name);
                Console.WriteLine("TaskDescription :" + tInstance.description);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------" + tInstance.name + "-------------");
            return tInstance;
        }
        public int CreateTask(Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskInstance instance)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoking CreateTask method");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            int retVal = taskClient.CreateTask(instance);
            Console.WriteLine("Task create successfully:ID=" + retVal.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            return retVal;
        }
        public void GetTaskStatus(int taskId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoking GetTaskStatus method");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------****-----------------");
            Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskStatus taskStatus = new Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskStatus();
            taskStatus = taskClient.GetTaskStatus(taskId);
            Console.WriteLine("Task status : " + taskStatus.taskStatus.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        }
        public void PerformTaskOperation(int taskId, string operation, String reason)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PerformTaskOperation method");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            int operationStatusCode = 0;
            operationStatusCode = taskClient.PerformTaskOperation(taskId, operation, reason);
            String updateSuccess = operationStatusCode == 1 ? "update success" : "update failed";
            Console.WriteLine("Returned Operation Status Code = " + operationStatusCode + "|| Updation status message:" + updateSuccess);
        }
        //public void GetTaskHistory(int taskId, int detailLevel)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("Invoking GetTaskHistory method");
        //    Console.WriteLine("------------------*****-----------------");
        //    Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskHistory taskHistory = new Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskHistory();
        //    taskHistory = taskClient.GetTaskHistory(taskId, detailLevel);
        //    if (taskHistory.listOfAllowedActions != null)
        //        foreach (Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskAllowedAction allowedAction in taskHistory.listOfAllowedActions)
        //        {
        //            Console.WriteLine("Task History - allowedAction : " + allowedAction.actionName);
        //            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        //        }
        //    if (taskHistory.listOfCustomAttributes != null)
        //        foreach (Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskCustomAttributes customAttribute in taskHistory.listOfCustomAttributes)
        //        {
        //            Console.WriteLine("Custom Attribute : " + customAttribute.key + " | Value:" + customAttribute.value);
        //            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        //        }
        //    if (taskHistory.taskinstanceEscalations != null)
        //        foreach (Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskEscaltion taskEscaltion in taskHistory.taskinstanceEscalations)
        //        {
        //            Console.WriteLine("Task Escaltion : " + taskEscaltion.escalationLevel + " | escalationType : " + taskEscaltion.escalationType);
        //            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        //        }
        //    if (taskHistory.taskInstanceUsers != null)
        //        foreach (Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskUser taskUser in taskHistory.taskInstanceUsers)
        //        {
        //            Console.WriteLine("Task User : " + taskUser.firstName + " ,  " + taskUser.lastName);
        //            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        //        }
        //    if (taskHistory.taskInstanceGroups != null)
        //        foreach (Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskGroup group in taskHistory.taskInstanceGroups)
        //        {
        //            Console.WriteLine("Group : " + group.groupName + "| escalationLevel : " + group.escalationLevel);
        //            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        //        }
        //    if (taskHistory.taskInstanceSkills != null)
        //        foreach (Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskSkill skill in taskHistory.taskInstanceSkills)
        //        {
        //            Console.WriteLine("Skill : " + skill.skillName + "| description : " + skill.description);
        //            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        //        }
        //    if (taskHistory.taskStatusList != null)
        //        foreach (Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskStatus taskStatus in taskHistory.taskStatusList)
        //        {
        //            Console.WriteLine("TaskStatus : " + taskStatus.taskStatus);
        //            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        //        }
        //    if (taskHistory.userTaskInstanceList != null)
        //        foreach (Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.UserTaskInstance userTaskInstance in taskHistory.userTaskInstanceList)
        //        {
        //            Console.WriteLine("UserTaskInstance status: " + userTaskInstance.status);
        //            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        //        }
        //    //taskHistory.listOfAllowedActions
        //}
        public void CreateTaskFromTemplate(Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TemplateData data)
        {
            //taskClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "USR";
            //taskClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "PWD";
            //taskClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

            Console.WriteLine("Invoking CreateTaskFromTemplate method");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------***-----------------");
            int taskId = taskClient.CreateTaskFromTemplate(siteID, data);
            Console.WriteLine("Created task from template with TaskId: " + taskId);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");

        }
    };
    class Program
    {
        static WebServiceFunctions wsf = new WebServiceFunctions();
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //
            //Initializing the excel sheet
            //
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:/WebServiceTemplate.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            //
            //Getting row count, column count and the number of sheets 
            //
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
            int numSheets = xlWorkbook.Sheets.Count;
            //
            // Iterate through the sheets. They are indexed starting at 1.
            //            
            for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++)
            {
                //
                // Do something with the data in the array with a custom method.
                //
                String strRetVal = xlRange.Cells[row, 3].Value;
                String strFunctionName = xlRange.Cells[row, 4].Value;
                String strParam1 = xlRange.Cells[row, 6].Value;
                String strParam2 = xlRange.Cells[row, 7].Value;
                String strParam3 = xlRange.Cells[row, 8].Value;
                String strParam4 = xlRange.Cells[row, 9].Value;
                TemplateData tData = new TemplateData();
                TaskInstance tInstance = new TaskInstance();
                int tID = 0;
                ProcessInput(strRetVal, strFunctionName, strParam1, strParam2, strParam3, strParam4, tData, tInstance, tID);
                //creating a task from templates in one flow
                //1)Get all templates.
                List<Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TemplateData> templateDataList = new List<TemplateData>();
                //bool createTaskFromTemplate_Flag = false;
                templateDataList = wsf.ReturnAllTemplateNames();
                //if (createTaskFromTemplate_Flag)
                //{
                //    foreach (TemplateData templateDataInst in templateDataList)
                //    {
                //        //We are not using the method CreateTaskFromTemplate for this application
                //        //WebServiceFunctions.CreateTaskFromTemplate(templateDataInst);
                //    }
                //}
                bool createTaskForAll = false;
                if (createTaskForAll)
                {
                    foreach (TemplateData templateDataInst in templateDataList)
                    {
                        //2)Get task instance
                        TaskInstance taskInstance = new TaskInstance();
                        taskInstance = wsf.ReturnTaskInstanceFromTemplate(templateDataInst);
                        taskInstance.scheduleActivity = new ScheduleActivity();
                        taskInstance.scheduleActivity.nextRun = new DateTime();
                        taskInstance.scheduleActivity.isRecurring = 0;
                        //over riding taskType in task
                        taskInstance.taskType = "pull";

                        //3)Create task.
                        wsf.CreateTask(taskInstance);
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    int numberOfTemplatesReturned = templateDataList.Count();
                    Random random = new Random();
                    int randomTemplateInList = random.Next(0, numberOfTemplatesReturned);
                    Console.WriteLine("Random number from template list:" + randomTemplateInList);
                    TemplateData templateDataInstance = new TemplateData();
                    templateDataInstance = templateDataList.ElementAt(randomTemplateInList);

                    //2)Get task instance
                    TaskInstance taskInstance = new TaskInstance();
                    taskInstance = wsf.ReturnTaskInstanceFromTemplate(templateDataInstance);

                   // 3)Create task.
                    tID = wsf.CreateTask(taskInstance);
                    wsf.GetTaskStatus(tID);
                    //int detailLevel = 2;
                   // Console.WriteLine("Task History for a newly created task would contain minimal details.");
                   // Console.WriteLine("Run method with taskId of a task which has gone through various phases to see detailed history.");
                   // wsf.GetTaskHistory(tID, detailLevel);
                }
               // Console.WriteLine("Updating status via update task status");
               //wsf.PerformTaskOperation(tID, "DELETE", "trying pauseeee");

               // Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Exit Client Application.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        public static void ProcessInput(String strRetVal, String strFunctionName, /*String strParamCount,*/ String strParam1, String strParam2, String strParam3, String strParam4, TemplateData tData, TaskInstance tInstance, int tID)
        {
            switch (strFunctionName)
            {
                case "ITemplate.GetAllTemplate":
                    {
                        //ITemplate.GetAllTemplate code
                        MessageBox.Show("ITemplate.GetAllTemplate");
                        wsf.GetAllTemplateNames(strParam1, strRetVal);
                        break;
                    }
                case "ITask.GetTaskInstanceFromTemplate":
                    {
                        //ITask.GetTaskInstanceFromTemplate code
                        MessageBox.Show("ITask.GetTaskInstanceFromTemplate");
                        wsf.GetTaskInstanceFromTemplate(tData);
                        break;
                    }
                case "CreateTask":
                    {
                        //CreateTask code
                        MessageBox.Show("CreateTask");
                       wsf.CreateTask(tInstance);
                        break;
                    }
                case "UpdateDatabase":
                    {
                        //UpdateDatabase code
                        MessageBox.Show("UpdateDatabase");
                        break;
                    }
                case "GetTaskStatus":
                    {
                        //GetTaskStatus code
                        MessageBox.Show("GetTaskStatus");
                        wsf.GetTaskStatus(tID);
                        break;
                    }
                case "VerifyValue":
                    {
                        //VerifyValue code
                        MessageBox.Show("VerifyValue");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: In your last case "VerifyValue", the break is outside of the {}. Could it be that?

Comment: Please do not post your entire program to stackoverflow, nobody is going to read up all your codes. Post only the important segment. read FAQ before you ask any question.

Comment: @Buddha ya ya it can be like that...

Comment: @Roylee ya ya i know dat friend...but my issue would b clear only if someone reads d entire code..dats why..

Comment: Try putting a break-point on the `switch` statement and step through the code to see what's happening

Comment: Your "break"s are wrongly placed.

Answer (score 0):

The call to ProcessInput() is in a loop.  Have you run this in debug?  That switch should work.  Are you sure a SINGLE call to ProcessInput runs all the case conditions?